# Run search in entire table

Tags: c#, sql, dataview

My program runs, client enters what he is looking for and it searches it in the SQL database. When he clicks on search, it appears in a datagridview.

I want the client to enter any word, beginning or end of a word and instead of looking in one column it will look in the entire table.

How do I program that?

clsdatasource.search gets what's in the textbox and stores it in a variable.

```
DataView myview = new DataView(mytable);
myview.RowFilter = "CUSTOMER='" + clsDataSource.search + "'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = myview;
```

What I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myset.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++) {
  DataRow[] MyDR = myset.Tables[0].Select(myset.Tables[0].Columns[i].ToString() + "='" +   clsDataSource.search + "'");
  if (MyDR.Length > 0) {
    dataGridView1.DataSource = myview;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could iterate through all rows and check each column for a partial string match.

Comment: So I just tried that but I have some columns that are storing date and time

Comment: Something like this may work: foreach(var r in gridView.Rows){ foreach(var c in r.Columns) { //code to search here where datatype != to DateTime} } Furthermore, if youre using linq you can do something like this in the inner foreach loop, I think: foreach(var c in r.Columns.Where( x=> x.DataType != typeof(DateTIme))

Comment: You need a better specification -- clearly client does not want timestamp columns -- so what do they actually want?  Sometimes clients make a problem very hard when what they actually want is simple.

Comment: Would it be efficient to use contains in my SQL statement and state the columns ?

Comment: @Hogan he doesn't want timestamp columns but wants last order date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    DataTable dataTable;
    DataView dataView;
    TextBox textBoxSearch;

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();

        Width = 400;
        dataGridView = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
        textBoxSearch = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = 200 };
        textBoxSearch.TextChanged += TextBoxSearch_TextChanged;

        dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(DateTime));

        dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Bob", new DateTime(2001, 01, 01));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "John", new DateTime(1999, 09, 09));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Alice", new DateTime(2002, 02, 02));

        dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
        dataGridView.DataSource = dataView;
    }

    private void TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = textBoxSearch.Text;

        var values = dataTable.Columns
            .OfType<DataColumn>()
            .Select(c => "Convert([" + c.ColumnName + "], System.String)")
            .Select(c => c + " like '%" + text + "%'");

        var filter = string.Join(" or ", values);

        dataView.RowFilter = filter;
    }
}
```

To search in all columns of different types, I convert them to strings. Then use the `like` operator. And, finally, combine with `or`.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying something similar to that but could not figure out how to take all the columns!